# Alter <img> with custom media field data

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, action, hook

I have used the following code to add some custom fields to my media attachment details...

```
function aj_attachment_field_audio_url( $form_fields, $post ) {

$form_fields['aj-audio-url'] = array(
    'label' => 'Audio File URL',
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'aj-audio_url', true ),
    'helps' => 'Add Audio URL',
);

return $form_fields;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'aj_attachment_field_audio_url', 10, 2 );

function aj_attachment_field_audio_url_save( $post, $attachment ) {

if( isset( $attachment['aj-audio-url'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'aj_audio_url', esc_url( $attachment['aj-audio-url'] ) );
return $post;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'aj_attachment_field_audio_url_save', 10, 2 );
?>
```

I'm now lost as to how to alter my img tags to include the new information with a data-audio_url="".

Basically anytime there is an image (added to content wysiwyg) with that field I would like to add that to the img tag.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using get_image_tag() will probably get your where you want. The below is not tested, but should work.

```
function get_image_tag( $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size ) {

    //Getting the meta data
    $aj_audio_url = get_post_meta( $id, 'aj_audio_url', true );

    //If not empty add the audio_url
    if ( ! empty( $aj_audio_url ) ) {
       $html = '<img src="' . esc_attr($img_src) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" ' . $title . $hwstring . 'class="' . $class . ' data-audio_url="' . $aj_audio_url .  '"/>';

       return apply_filters( 'get_image_tag', $html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size );
    }
}
```

Get more info and examples here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/